# How to expand div from center instead of top left

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a login form centered in the middle of the screen with this CSS:

```
.login-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: block;

  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px 40px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0.4px 0.4px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.109),
    0 1px 1px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.155),
    0 2.1px 2.1px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.195),
    0 4.4px 4.4px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.241),
    0 12px 12px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.35);
}
```

After the user logs in I want to expand the div to 100% to show other content. After the user has pressed the login button the class of the div changes to this CSS:

```
.full{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

It does the job, but the div moves to the top left corner and starts expanding from there. How to make it expand from the middle?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the class, add it:

```
document.getElementById("div-id").className += " full";
```

Comment: Now it just skips to width and height 100% without any transition

Comment: try this     transition: all 2s ease;

Answer (score 0):

You can try using tranform for this. In your initial class, set the X scale to 0 and transform the origin to the center. Then in your animation class, just change thr X scale to 1 and transition the change like this :

```
.login-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: block;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin : 50%;


.full {
transform : scaleX(1);
transition : transform 200ms ease-in;
}
```